# Device not accepting mobile provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Ive created an ad-hoc provisioning profile that includes the device that I want to test in. It is a 4th gen. iPod Touch running iOS 5.1. When I drag the mobile provision file into my iPod in iTunes, I get a message that the application cannot run in my device and hence the provisioning file cannot be added. My app is built with deployment target set at iOS 4.3 and base SDK as iOS 5.1.

What could be the issue?

Comment: is your device known development device? usually when I plug new device, xcode asks me if I want to use the device for development.

Comment: Do you add the app or provisioning profile to device?

Comment: My device is already configured for development and I also selected the device while creating the provisioning profile.